# How do I put my Stack Exchange flair into my Gmail signature?

Tags: support, flair

I am using Gmail and I want to put my Stack Overflow flair into my signature.

Raw HTML doesn't work so the only alternative is to download the image, but obviously it doesn't update.

Has anyone managed to do this?

Comment: You don't. Seriously. Never **ever** use HTML signatures. Stop.

Comment: Ok, call me an idiot for asking but why?

Comment: In all seriousness though, [this](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/08/how-to-add-html-signatures-with-images.html) site should help. I get really irritated when I see html signatures because it eventually leads to `<blink>` tags and straight to my blacklist - anyway, that's just my preference :)

Comment: Cheers, also I didn't think about that element at all, good point =)

Comment: @MarvinPinto Obviously you forgot about `<marquee>`. :D

Comment: _This e-mail best viewed in Netscape Navigator 4.72. [Netscape Now!](http://www.oldapps.com/netscape.php?old_netscape=29)_ @TheUnicornWhisperer

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/how-to-add-an-image-to-my-gmail-signature

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you have two options.

1. Rather than pasting raw HTML, simply copy the flair that has been rendered by your browser and paste *that* into your signature. I did a quick test and it worked for me. To check it yourself, send a test message and click **Show original** on it: the signature should contain more or less the same code that is shown on the **flair** tab of your profile.
2. Click the **Insert Image** button while composing your signature and enter the URL for your flair (in your case, `http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/941638.png`). The image should update automatically because it references a URL, but I haven't confirmed that yet.

Comment: I believe the OP wants it to _update_, so this won't really work.

Comment: Does it update when your rep does though?

Comment: @JMK That's a good question (at most, it would update when your flair does - which is every 24-36 hours).

Comment: @MarvinPinto I clicked **Show original** on the message that I sent and it contains more or less the same code that is shown on the **flair** tab of my profile.

Comment: @Chris Interesting! I wasn't aware of how that worked.

Comment: Cheers guys, got it working =)

Answer (score 5):

Use this Steps:

Go to your profile flair and copy your Image Link

[image: Go to your profile flair and copy your Image Link]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> **I'll show you the best way because your picture gonna has the link to SE
>   profile.**

Step 1:

Copy your `flier html` into a file called `signature.html`

[image]

[image]

Step 2:

Open your `signature.html` file in your favorite browser, select and copy de content:

[image]

Step 3:

Finally, paste into your Gmail signature:

[image]